# what is the extention of windows store application

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

I tried to install my new windows store application on my mobile but I didn't get the installation file. So please tell me how to install windows store application on mobile and tell me the extension of windows store application.

Comment: What mobile? Windows store application *usually* refer to Windows 8 (RT or Pro).

Comment: The extension is typically ".appx" or perhaps ".appxbundle".

Comment: When you say WPF and Windows Store App - do you actually mean WPF or is it WinRT XAML?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want...

If you are talking about installing a Windows Phone app to a device, you first need to run the Windows Phone Developer Registration utility to unlock the device for debugging and testing. After that, you can run your app in two ways: 1) from Visual Studio: select the device as the target and run the app, or 2) deploy your XAP using the Application Deployment utility.

If you are talking about a Windows 8 app, then: 1) you can run it on the Local (or Remote) Machine from Visual Studio, or 2) you can install the package to a computer with a developer license as explained in this post: http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/installing-windows-8-app-package.html